# Rotating a UIImage to point in the right direction defined by calculated angle

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview, rotation, uiimage

I have a cartoon character in a UIImage that is added as a subview to my main UIView.  I take the centre coordinates of the image along with a randomly generated CGPoint and use trig to find the angle that the character needs to rotate to point in the right direction. I use UIView animation within a block. The first part does the rotate, then the completion for the first part does the move to the new location, then the completion for the inner block calls the animation loop again.  This rotate/move sequence continues until the user stops it - so essentially, the character is continually moving around the screen.

It seems to be working for the first rotate/move sequence, but then it starts to face the wrong way. I've looked at the angles and they seem to be calculating correctly (I get that negative goes counter clockwise), so I'm wondering if there's something in how the translate to the new location and its associated new coordinates work?  I've tried doing this with blocks, without blocks, changing to layers and using CGAffine functions, but this should be quite simple and easy to do with UIView animations.

In short, I'm stumped and need some help or pointers in the right direction. I'm probably missing something obvious so forgive me if that's the case but I've been at this for two weeks now so I'm a bit 'can't see the woods for the trees'!!

The pertinent code:  I add the character (theBug), which is a custom class (that subclasses the UIImageView):

```
if (!doesContain){
    NSLog(@"adding bug for first time");
    //doesContain=YES; //set this at the end of the method after first call to animateLoop
    [self.theBug setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
    self.theBug=[[BugView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newbug1.png"]];
    self.theBug.tag=3; //to identiry this in clearBoard
    self.theBug.frame=CGRectMake(100, 100, 30, 30);
    [self.gameView addSubview:self.theBug];
    self.gameView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    self.theBug.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
}
```

The I do the animation:

```
//Random x&y points
CGFloat x=(CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.gameView.frame.size.width);
CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.gameView.frame.size.height);

//create the random point to move the bug to
CGPoint rotateToLocation= CGPointMake(x, y);

//Store the bug's current location - This might not be the best way to represent this after rotation
CGPoint bugLocation = CGPointMake(self.theBug.frame.origin.x, self.theBug.frame.origin.y);

//Calculate the angle to rotate
float angleToRotate = atan2f(self.theBug.transform.tx-rotateToLocation.x,   self.theBug.transform.ty - rotateToLocation.y);
if (self.theBug.transform.tx <x)
    angleToRotate*=-1;


double delayInSeconds = 1;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
[UIView animateWithDuration:4
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
                 animations:^{
                     self.theBug.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.theBug.transform, angleToRotate);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:4
                                           delay:0.0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                                      animations:^{
                                          self.theBug.center = rotateToLocation;
                                      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                          [self animationLoop:@"bug" finished:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] context:nil];
                                      }];

    }];

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple!  My calculations were correct, the problem was my starting image was oriented incorrectly. I rotated the original image to the right position and it all worked fine.